# LESS CSS Hierarchical Heritance

Tags: css, less

In a project I have separated the CSS into two sub-projects:

- C:/Projects/_Framework/css
- C:/Projects/_Base/css

*Note: I've purposely prefixed the above with the `C:/Projects/` to illustrate that they are totally separate projects from each other.*

The `_Framework` has basic things like reset, typography, forms, and a grid.

The `_Base` has the default theme for the project. `_Base` imports the `_Framework`

Inside `_Base` I have files like `header.less` and `variables.less` which store the design of the header and the colours for the theme.

So if I have my project at: `C:/Projects/App`

And inside this App project, I have a master CSS file that looks like:

```
@import "/_Framework/_loadAll.less
@import "/_Base/_loadAll.less
```

Which imports both the Framework and the Base theme (the reason that Base doesn't load the Framework itself is for flexibility but has scope to be done this way instead if needed).

The plan is to make it so that if a `header.less` file existed inside `_App` then it would automatically override the import of the one in `_Base`.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can't exclude a whole `.less` file by checking for duplicate names. Just make sure that the `header.less`file of your `_App` project is imported **after** the one from `_Base`.

Pseudo code:

```
@import "/_Framework/_loadAll.less
@import "/_Base/_loadAll.less
@import "_App/header.less"
```

And overwrite any properties you need in the `_App/header.less` file.

If you need to overwrite everything in the `_Base/header.less` file, I would suggest it's not a good fit for a Base style.